# Run the same C++ Program from different Binary Names

Tags: c++

Okay, for a homework assignment my professor wants us to write a program in C++ that converts from miles to km.  I did all that, the program runs.  However, he has this special way of calling the program:

> The program's usage options are based
>   on the NAME of the BINARY FILE.  If
>   the program name is 'km2miles', the
>   program interprets the command line
>   argument as a kilometer value to
>   convert to miles.  If the name is
>   'miles2km', then it interprets as
>   miles being converted to km. Since the
>   first command line argument, argv[0]
>   is always the program's name, you can
>   use its value to decide which function
>   to call.

I only have 3 files in this project (he tells us to ONLY have these 3):
convert.cpp
distance.cpp
distance.h

Distance .h and .cpp have the different functions to convert Mi to Km and Vice Versa, the convert.cpp has the main function.  However, the only way I know how to call this program (after compiling it) is to say:

./convert 10

Where 10 is the number to convert.  He says it should be called like this:

```
$ km2miles 100
```

and

```
$ miles2km 60
```

I have no idea how to get the program to act differently by having a different name... especially when that name doesn't even run the program!  Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

- specify a name when you build it, and build it twice
- on Windows: `copy convert miles2kms; copy convert kms2miles`
- on UNIX/Linux: `cp convert miles2kms; cp convert kms2miles`
- on UNIX/Linx (better): make a link or symbolic link: `ln -s convert miles2kms; ln -s convert kms2miles`.

Inside your program, you should be doing something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::string program_name = argv[0];

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "usage: " << program_name << " <value>\n";
        return 0;
    }
    if (/* TODO: what would go here? */)
        ...
    else
        ...
}
```

Comment: Why not `std::string program_name(argv[0]);`?  Oh, and for an *extreme* example of this technique. look up [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/).

Comment: Hi Mike... just a stylistic choice.  C++ guarantees they're equivalent in this case, but I find the assignment notation more readable.  Great example in busybox.

Comment: Hi Tony, actually the assignment notation is quite different to the constructor notation.
In the case of the assignment the default constructor of std::string is called first, then the constructor with char* is called and the assignment method is called.
std::string program_name(argv[0]) just calls the char* constructor.

Of course in a scenario where you would only call the code once (like our example here) it is more a style issue and it might be more readable to use the assignment notation. In other scenarios this way of constructing an object can be very expensive.

Comment: @Behrang: sound reasoning, but incomplete premises.  The compiler is allowed to (and can reasonably be expected to) elide the assignment into a direct call to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions already tell you how:

> Since the first command line argument, **argv[0] is always the program's name**, you can use its value to decide which function to call.
>
> especially when that name doesn't even run the program!

If you're using gcc, by default it generates a binary named `a.out`, but you can rename it to be whatever you want. (Or you can specify the name of the output file via the `-o` command-line option.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, he gave you one clue with the argv[0] thing.

Did you perhaps discuss symbolic links at some point in your class?

Difficult for me to give more hints without actually giving away the answer.

Comment: I don't recall talking about symbolic links at all in class, just details about the make file and compiling.  I understand that argv[0] is the program name, but I need to call the program with that, so:
"./convert 10", in the terminal.  In which case the name is Convert.  If I type: "./km2miles 10" it simply complains about there not being a name for the program.

Comment: Just do `cp convert km2miles;./km2miles 10`. Copying files is easier to understand (you yourself have probably done it thousands of times) so start with that. Then read up on links and the `ln` command (sort of like shortcuts in the Windows world).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to recompile the same code into 2 different executable files then you may need to use a symbolic link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link